# How do I lock all fields (CTRL-A, CTRL-F11) on a word doc using Open XML SDK in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have a word document that contains macros that is downloaded form a third party. After the document is saved and opened it looks great, but when I go to print it, it loses the data that was applied with the macro and shows "Error! Reference source not found!". I found that if I press CTRL-A and CTRL-F11, it will lock all the fields. After that I go to print and my data is there. I would like to use Open XML SDK utility to load up this document and apply this locking to the word document before it's saved. Is this possible? I have document loading up, but I just can't seem to find how to set the fields to locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to lock the fields for the entire document - each field needs to be locked individually when working with the Word Open XML. It requires the [`FieldLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.fieldchar.fieldlock.aspx) property of the [`FieldChar` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.fieldchar.aspx).

This corresponds to the xml

```
<w:r>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="start" w:fldLock="true"/>
</w:r>
```

The following snippet locks all the field codes in the document.

```
    using (WordprocessingDocument pkgDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileNameDoc, true))
    {
        int countFields = 0;
        Body body = pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        FieldChar[] fieldchars = (FieldChar[]) body.Descendants<FieldChar>().ToArray();
        foreach (FieldChar fc in fieldchars)
        {
            fc.FieldLock = true;
            countFields++;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(countFields.ToString() + " fields locked");

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm. I also had to do similar to the header and footer, but it solved my issue.